# Firestore Angular Collection inside Document

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents for every instructor and I want to have another collection of comments for each doc. I can't find a way to read that sub collection. Here is the structure:

[image: Structure pt1]

[image: Structure pt2]

I take the specific id from a service here:

```
getInstructor(iid: string) {
    this.instructorDoc = this.afs.doc<Instructors>(`instructors/${iid}`);
    return this.instructorDoc.valueChanges();  
}
```

I call the function on the instructor page:

```
getInstructor(): void {
    const iid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('iid');
    this.instructorsService.getInstructor(iid).subscribe(instructor => this.instructor = instructor);   
}
```

I also have an interface for instructors:

```
export interface Instructors {
  iid: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  category: string;
  location: string;
  description: string;
  photoURL: string;
}
```

Finally I have the html of the instructor component like this:

```
<div *ngIf="instructor" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img [src]="instructor.photoURL || '//:0'" alt="" class="card-img-top">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ instructor.iid }} {{ instructor.first_name }} {{ instructor.last_name }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
      content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the code works. I'm just stuck and can't figure how to go from here. Should I declare the comments somehow in the instructor interface? Also should somehow take the id of the comment (maybe add cid field in the comment doc). And how I will show the comment content in the html. I'm new to JavaScript/TypeScript/Angular and maybe these things are easy but I wasn't able to find helpful info on google on the specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following in order to retrieve a Comment document:

```
getComment(iid: string, commentId: string) {
    this.commentDoc = this.afs.doc<Comment>(
        `instructors/${iid}/comments/${commentId}`
    );
    return this.commentDoc.valueChanges();  
}
```

With this interface or similar:

```
export interface Comment {
    id?: string;
    content: string;
}
```

About getting the comment ID, I think it really depends on what you are doing. For example if you were to have a post with multiple comments of multiple people, if a comment can be interacted with it would be a good idea to leave the comment ID inside an HTML tag so it can be retrieved to perform a query with it. In another scenario you may want to iterate on all the comments, which would be different.

That last aspect of your question may need more clarification and it's probably worth of another question going into more detail about your application.

---

After discussing the problem in the comments I found that there's a lack of understanding about the application's workflow. I will try to explain what is missing and I will show how to fix it.

## Misconception

The designed web has the routes defined in `src/app/app-routing.module.ts`. There are these routes defined:

```
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/instructors',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'instructors',
    component: InstructorsComponent
},
{
    path: 'instructors/:iid',
    component: InstructorDetailsComponent,
}
```

We can understand from there that `/instructors` will act as the index page and `/instructors/:iid` will be the detail of each instructor.

When a user goes to your main page and clicks on the profile of an instructor, notice how you are accessing `/instructors/:iid`. Thus, you are *only* forwarding the id of the instructor (`iid`). This is correct because we don't have the need to forward this on the URL, we are only inspecting the instructor.

```
const cid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('cid');
```

Therefore the line above in the file `instructor-details.component.ts` doesn't make sense because it retrieves the parameter `cid` which it's not being forwarded on the URL for the instructor's details.

Actually if that line is changed to `const cid = "a8OA7dCBNuNE8uTwgvhk"` you will see that the whole function works and it's displayed properly on the page of the first instructor (`5EdG4liyxxjam9BrCt0T`).

## Fix

As I understand, you want to show all the comments of an instructor on their details page. This means that the application has to retrieve the subcollection `comments` of the appropriate instructor and display them.

In order to solve this I have modified three files:

**instructor-details.component.ts**

First the retrieval of the parameter `cid` has to be removed, as it will never be there. The following setup tells us that the function `InstructorsService.getComments` will retrieve all the comments of the instructor `iid` and return them in order to display them.

```
getComments(): void {
    const iid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('iid');
    this.instructorsService.getComments(iid).subscribe(comments => {
        this.comments = comments;
    });
}
```

**instructors.service.ts**

Now this function has to retrieve the whole collection of comments instead of a single one having the id. Notice that the `commentDoc` has now changed to `commentCol` and has changed its type, as the query is now retrieving a whole collection instead of a single document.

```
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection} from '@angular/fire/firestore';

[..]

export class InstructorsService {
    instructorDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Instructors>;
    commentCol: AngularFirestoreCollection<Comments>;

    [..]

    getComments(iid: string) {
        this.commentCol = this.afs.collection<Comments>(`instructors/${iid}/comments`);
        return this.commentCol.valueChanges();
    }

}
```

**instructor-details.component.html**

In the HTML component, instead of displaying the value, it has been changed to the iterator `ngFor`, since the component is now receiving a *list* of documents.

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments"> {{comment.content}} </div>
```

Comment: I want every user to be able to comment on every instructor page so ye I want multiple comments from multiple ppl. I add what you suggest and this to html: 

<div *ngIf="comments">
  {{comments.content}}
</div>

But content doesn't appear.

Comment: What does the retrieval return? Log the content in there to know if there's a problem retrieving the information or displaying it.

Comment: The problem with that code is that `cid` is `undefined` when retrieved at `InstructorDetailsComponent.getComments`. If I hardcode `cid` with the value `a8OA7dCBNuNE8uTwgvhk` I can see the content "123asd" in James Smith's profile.

Comment: But how its undefined? I mean why instructor.first_name is not undefined? I declared them the same way on interfaces. Am I missing something? Again sorry if its stupid easy but I don't have much experience with all these.

Comment: The problem is the line `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('cid')`, that returns `undefined`, you are getting no comments because that function doesn't return a valid comment ID. You should add the parameter `cid` the same way you add the `iid` one to be later retrieved on that line.

Comment: I see it null on console but still I can't understand how the functions doesn't work. Its the same way with the ```iid``` one

Comment: The thing is that the functions work, they are just not receiving the argument `cid` that you are retrieving in there. Look at your `app-routing.module.ts` file, in there you state that the value `iid` will be sent on the URI, so you can retrieve it from inside the component `InstructorDetailsComponent`. Note that `cid` is not specified anywhere, thus, it's not sent and cannot be retrieved. Still, hardcoding the `cid` to a valid value shows that the function does work since it successfully displays the comment.

Comment: Clearly in this case, the `cid` shouldn't be sent as an argument in the instructor's URI, but inside the page you should access all comments and print them.

Comment: I get the idea but I really stuck. I tried many ways but i cant retrieve the comment properties and I can't understand how its not working I do the same think as with the instructors.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution to your problem. Let me know if there's something missing or that you don't understand. If my answer has helped you understand and fix your issue, please, accept it.

Comment: You helped me so much. I see now what I was missing, the way to retrieve the sub-collection. Thank you very much!